# Merge arrays only adding new elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hey I'm breaking my head over something that should be very simple.  I have a few arrays

```
//input

var array1 = ["white", "white", "yellow"];
var array2 = ["white", "white", "yellow", "red"];
var array3 = ["white", "white", "yellow", "orange"];

//desired output

var result = ["white", "white", "yellow", "red", "orange"];
```

This should be a simple problem but I just haven't been able to wind my head around it.  I tried by using a snapshot of the first array, then see if the color was already in the snapshot array remove it from the snapshot, put it in another snapshot etc... but I ended up with lines and lines of code.  Couldn't even get it to work since I was deleting all "white" colors from the snapshot instead of just one and other things where going wrong.

Cans someone give me a second perspective, cause I'm running against a wall atm

My last attempt as asked to provide the code

```
    let attacks = entry.attacks;
    if(attacks !== undefined){
        let lastSnapshot = [];

        attacks.forEach(attack => {
            if(lastSnapshot.length === 0){
                attack.forEach(attackColor => {
                    lastSnapshot.push(attackColor)
                })                        
            }else{
                let newSnapshot = [];
                attack.forEach(attackColor => {
                    var start_index = lastSnapshot.findIndex(attackColor)
                    if(start_index !== -1){
                        var number_of_elements_to_remove = 1;
                        lastSnapshot.splice(start_index, number_of_elements_to_remove);                                
                    }

                    newSnapshot.push(attackColor)
                })
                lastSnapshot = newSnapshot;                              
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: The output should be like this `var result = ["white", "yellow", "red", "orange"];` why duplicate `while` value inside array?

Comment: Also duplicating only white,why not duplicating yellow?

Comment: can  the number of arrays , 3 atm,  increase

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1584377/6178832

Comment: Is order important?

Comment: @charlieftl order is not of any importance

Comment: @brk I'm not duplicating anything, white started out with two already I want to merge all arrays, but with each merge only add new elements

Comment: @Helpinghand

the arrays can be any number of arrays I choose an example of three in this post not to overcomplicate things

Comment: Why don't you try lodash?

Comment: @kenny Check my answer May be It will save your some extra code of lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `reduce` for the arrays and a `forEach` for single items of the array for adding items to `r`.

Then a hash table is used to store the visited items and their last index of the temporary result array `r`. If no item is found, the actual value is pushed.

```js
var array1 = ["white", "white", "yellow"],
    array2 = ["white", "white", "yellow", "red"],
    array3 = ["white", "white", "yellow", "orange"],
    result = [array1, array2, array3].reduce((r, a) => {
        var indices = Object.create(null);
        a.forEach(b => {
            var p = r.indexOf(b, indices[b] || 0);
            indices[b] = p === -1 ? r.push(b) : p + 1;
        });
        return r;
    });
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: `var p = r.includes(b);             if (!p) {
                r.push(b);
            } else {
                indices[b] = p;
            }` Is a bit easier to read to me and does the same I believe

Comment: i need the index of the found item for the next search.

Comment: Thanks Nina your code works perfectly and is vanilla javascript

Comment: @NinaScholz Yeah I see what you're doing now, interesting that I can't get it to fail without the index, but Array.includes() can take an index - anyhow, good answer

Comment: @NinaScholz My concept is not clear about this thing, can you give me some hint about this when we should use `Object.create(null)`  than `{}`?

Comment: I had to stare at that for a while to figure it out, but it's *really* nice. +1

Comment: `Object.create(null)` chrates a really empty object without prototypes like `toString`. by using this empty object, you could use it if the values are `toString` for caching the index. the plain object `{}` does not work for all kind of keys, because of the prototypes. the decision when to use an empty object instead of a plain object is maily driven by the expected values. if unclear use the empty one to be on the safer side.

Comment: Yesss, Nina's razor sharp mind strikes again. Nice one!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way also with `Set`, `Spread` and `forEach`.

```js
var array1 = ["white", "white", "yellow"];
var array2 = ["white", "white", "yellow", "red"];
var array3 = ["white", "white", "yellow", "orange"];
var merged = Array.from(new Set(array2.concat(array3)));
var desired = [...array1];
merged.forEach(function(element, index) {
  if (array1.indexOf(element) == -1) {
    desired.push(element);
  }
})
console.log(desired)
```

**Spread Syntax:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

**Set:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

**forEach:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: Thanks your code works and luckily I can use the spread operator in my little project.  However Nina Scholz code works as well and she is using vanilla javascript.  I feel inclined giving the right answer to her ... hope you don't mind

Comment: @kenny nope didn't mind because I've learn a lot on SO from Nina Scholz, she is my idol in JS. Glad it helps you somehow. Best of luck. `FYI:` my version is also Vanilla JS :)

Comment: it is ?  cause when using the ... operator I need to add the following to my projects

        "plugins": [
          "transform-async-to-generator", "transform-class-properties", "transform-object-rest-spread"
        ],

btw: I'm a java developer learning react javascript so there is a lot not evident to me  yet

Comment: please add as `var array2 = ["white", "white", "yellow", "red", "red"];` and try your algo. as it looks like, it never adds the second `"red"` because you just check with `includes`.